# No Java available even if SDK is configured

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk

I pulled the project from Github and opened the project in IntelliJ.
    For the first time I got the notification that the SDK is not configured, even if I have all the paths added (as you can see on the screenshots).
    I tried to find a similar problem, however I get answers how to add the path etc., but I already have it added, but IntelliJ doesn't recognize Java.
    Do you perhaps have any idea what could go wrong?
    Thank you in advance!

Screenshots:`enter code here`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOvfC.png)

[image]`enter code here`
[image]
[image]

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you run the program? Can post the notification.

Comment: Actually I cannot run the program...

Comment: Is it a maven based project? Or dependencies are configured only in IDE?

Comment: Yes, this is Maven based project.

Comment: Could you click on pom.xml and Open as a maven project?
The problem seems that IDE haven't resolved the source and test-source folder, after opening as a maven project **src->test** folder should be marked green as test sources root. Also could you attach a screenshot of **Modules** tab in project settings?

Comment: @AlexanderTerekhov Thank you very much for your hint! When clicking on the POM file and adding this as a Maven project - it helped!